# Brute force against DES

Tags: brute-force-attack

Let a plain text message `M` be DES encrypted with two different keys (`K1` and `K2`) to produce the encrypted messages `E1` and `E2` (for `K1` and `K2` respectively).

Lets assume we setup a brute force attack which tests all possible keys `K1` and `K2` until the decrypted messages `M1` and `M2` are equal.

Is it <s>mathematically</s> possible to find two different keys `K1'` and `K2'` so that the decrypted messages `M1` and `M2` are same (not necessarily equal to `M`) and `K1'` is different from `K1` and/or `K2'` is different from `K2`?

**EDIT:**

This question is not a homework actually. It is rather in the context of reverse-engineering. To give more context:

I gathered a few sample data from two sources. Parts of those samples encrypt the same plain text with different keys. I found out that there are 64bits patterns (i.e.: the data is encrypted by blocks of 64bits - date, operation code, etc.). From this I assume a most-likely DES/3DES/Blowfish/XTEA algorithms as they are the most common and most easily implemented on an embedded target.

I was wondering whether it could be worth a try (/practical) to run all possible keys and find the valid one with the condition "`M1` is same as `M2`".

Comment: Hint for what could be homework: as a first order approximation, assume that $K\mapsto D_K(E_1)$ and $K\mapsto D_K(E_2)$  (where $D_K$ is decryption with key $K$) behave as two independent random functions.

Comment: @fgrieu I'm afraid I don't understand .. What would this mean with a more literal language?

Comment: Hint, expanded: The properties of a good block cipher are such that it's reasonable to assume that when you fix an `E1`, the result of decrypting that `E1` with any number of distinct keys behaves essentially like as many independent random numbers as there are keys. Same if you fix an `E2`, with no relationship between the seemingly random results obtained in the two experiments if `E2`≠`E1`.

Comment: So the answer may be "yes, from a probability point of view, it is possible to have keys `K1'` and `K2'` so that `M1` and `M2` are same and `K1'` != `K1` and/or `K2'` != `K2`" .. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: The [current proposal](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/235693) lacks a justification of why it's probably true. Your task is to find such justification with the help of the above hint, and some more: you need considerations about the key and block size of DES, and the birthday problem. I think that's all the hints you'll get from moderators for probable homework, at least unless you show what you have done and where you are stuck.

Comment: @fgrieu more than random functions; they are pseudo-random permutations (though DES fails to be PRP since weak keys)

Comment: @fgrieu I updated the question so that it gives more context to explain why I am asking this question.. I tried to lay my question as factual/mathematical as possible but I do not necessarily expect a purely mathematical justification as I'm not from crypto background ..

Comment: What does " I identified 64bits patterns" mean? What kind of patterns? Do you mean (blocks of) identical ciphertext?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I mean that the encrypted message (3*16 bytes) expose some 8-bytes blocks format for the date, the operation, etc. For instance, two consecutive operations the same day only change 8 bytes of the encrypted message.

Comment: That would likely indicate ECB mode and an 8 byte block cipher. So what you may be looking for are attack vectors against ECB. The chances of blocks "colliding", i.e. having the same value by chance is not that high, so if multiple blocks are the same then the same key is likely used.

Comment: @kelalaka: DES for fixed data block is a function $\{0,1\}^{56}\to\{0,1\}^{64}$ which is not a permutation (and it's relatively easy to exhibit a collision). Independently: in a PRP, a vanishing number of weak keys does no go against the security property, because it's stated for random key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the question as originally asked with a single pair of $E_1$ and $E_2\ne E_1$ that have been obtained as $E_1=\operatorname{DES-Enc}_{K_1}(M)$ and $E_2=\operatorname{DES-Enc}_{K_2}(M)$ for unknown $M$, it's likely there are many pairs $(K'_1,K'_2)$ such that $\operatorname{DES-Dec}_{K'_1}(E_1)=\operatorname{DES-Dec}_{K'_2}(E_2)$. So it's very unlikely that the first pair found is the correct $(K_1,K_2)$, and there's no way to tell which pair found is right.

Argument: A good block cipher such as DES is such that for a fixed block $E_1$, the function $K\mapsto\operatorname{DES-Dec}_K(E_1)$ behaves mostly like a pseudo-random function (*not* permutation). And the other function obtained for $E_2\ne E_1$ is nearly independent, except for the relatively minor detail that $\operatorname{DES-Dec}_K(E_1)\ne\operatorname{DES-Dec}_K(E_2)$. In (simple) DES, the key is 56 effective bits, and a block is 64-bit. If we try $2^{32}$ distinct $K'_1$ (e.g. incremental) and compute $\operatorname{DES-Dec}_{K'_1}(E_1)$, we'll obtain a set of very nearly $2^{32}$ distinct random-like 64-bit values (more than 2 collisions is quite unlikely). If then we try some distinct $K'_2$, compute $\operatorname{DES-Dec}_{K'_2}(E_2)$ and check if it is in the set, that has probability nearly $2^{-32}$. Thus just above $2^{32}$ attempts are expected to find a suitable $K'_2$. But because we have explored only a proportion $2^{-24}$ of the possible $K'_1$, and about $2^{-24}$ of the possible $K'_2$, there's probability about $2^{-48}$ that we hit the right $(K_1,K_2)$.

---

With two or more distinct pairs of $(E_1,E_2)$, it's quite likely there is a single solution $(K'_1,K'_2)$, and thus that the first one found is the actual $(K_1,K_2)$. However it becomes much more difficult to exhibit that correct pair.

In theory a [Meet-in-the-Middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) attack needs like $2^{57}$ DES operations (for essentially guaranteed success assuming the block cipher is DES), but requires too much RAM for practice. Variants require manageable RAM and can be efficiently distributed, and require only a few times more work. While $2^{58}$ DES operations with key derivation is feasible ([it was in 1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFF_DES_cracker)), that's still not an easy task.

---

For a good 128-bit key cipher (3DES/Blowfish/TEA/XTEA), forget about a practical attack, even if $M$ was also known.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanations. I guess my real-case experiment somehow stops here then ..